# Xamarin Connectivity plugin always throws NotImplementedException

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I am trying to use Xam.Plugin.Connectivity 2.3.0 by James Montemagno in my Cross platform Xamarin app. The package is installed in all the three projects i.e. protable, android and iOS. But whenever i try to check connectivity, it throws NotImplementedException. This behaviour is independent of whether i try to access it in the portable or platform specific project. This is the code with which i try to access it

```
if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
{
    //business logic
}
```

The exception details are as follows

System.NotImplementedException: This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly. You should reference the NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation.

I have read similar posts on various forums, but none helped.

Comment: Did you try uninstalling and reinstalling the package in all platforms?

Comment: @StevenThewissen yeah just now tried without any relief.

Comment: Is it possible to upload the code somewhere to take a look at what might be configured wrong?

Comment: the application is being developed for my company and it's policies don't allow me to share any code. But i can confirm that this is the only code piece i have written regarding this plugin. and busines logic is not even being triggered

Comment: Understandable. I'm still thinking its a configuration thing where not all of the required packages got installed in all the platforms, hence my initial post about reinstalling the packages.

Comment: hmm. tried that. The package is working fine in my colleague's machine.  But still this thing will bug me until i find out why it didn't work in my pc. She has also installed the same nuget and used the same code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145615/discussion-between-steven-thewissen-and-its-a-trap).

Comment: I had the same problem. Added the package to all platforms, still same error. After removing the plugin and reinstalling it to all platforms and a clean and rebuild of the solution it works! Strange thing.

Answer (score 0):

I have this

[image]

version installed and it works for me. download and install same version and try again. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.  Finally I found out that I only added the Xam.Plugin.Connectivity in PCL but I didn't add the package in the Android folder too.  You add the package in Android folder again and it should works.